# Why computing inverse trigonometric functions is cheaper than computing the functions themselves?

Tags: javascript, performance, math, physics, trigonometry

## Long story short

I ran the following code on my browser:

```js
function test(f) {
  const start = performance.now();
  for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    f(i);
  }
  const end = performance.now();
  return (end - start) / 1000;
}

function bigTest() {
  let cosResults = [];
  let acosResults = [];
  let sinResults = [];
  let asinResults = [];
  let tanResults = [];
  let atanResults = [];
  let atan2Results = [];
  let sumResults = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    cosResults.push(test(Math.cos));
    acosResults.push(test(Math.acos));
    sinResults.push(test(Math.sin));
    asinResults.push(test(Math.asin));
    tanResults.push(test(Math.tan));
    atanResults.push(test(Math.atan));
    atan2Results.push(test((a) => Math.atan2(a, a)));
    sumResults.push(test((a) => a + 2 * a));
  }
  return {
    cos: cosResults.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 50,
    acos: acosResults.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 50,
    sin: sinResults.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 50,
    asin: asinResults.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 50,
    tan: tanResults.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 50,
    atan: atanResults.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 50,
    atan2: atan2Results.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 50,
    sum: sumResults.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) / 50
  };
}

console.log(bigTest());
```

And this is the result I got:

```
tan:    0.02815s
atan2:  0.02225s
cos:    0.01768s
sin:    0.01767s
atan:   0.01137s
acos:   0.00717s
asin:   0.00662s
sum:    0.00401s
```

Why computing `arc sine` and `arc cosine` is  cheaper than `sine` and `cosine`?

## Long story

I'm writing a real-time simulation and I need to find out the angle between two vectors to compare it with a rest angle. I know that dot product gives me the cosine, but I didn't want to rely on `acos` since it's supposedly very expensive.

Then I decided to check how expensive it was and formulated the test above. The results surprised me, and now I want to know why. Judging from my results, `acos` doesn't seem to be that bad.

Comment: As I read the code, you're passing integers from 0 to 999999 to your functions. Most of these will be outside the domain of acos so presumably the function can return NaN very early, after a single comparison.  This argument doesn't explain the atan performance, though.

Comment: @MvG Sounds like a reasonable assumption. What happens if the call is changed to `f(i/1000000.0)` or using a randomly generated number between 0 and 1 (`Math.random()`)?